# Content Orgniser automation with SPD Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, content

If a user enters the location wrong and the document ends up in the wrong place. I have written an SPD workflow which then moves the document back to the drop off library, but when the document arrives back in the drop off it does not automatically route the document. I have to go to properties and click on submit. Is there a way of moving a document within the content organiser without this additional step. Is there a REST url I can use or something which will automatically kick off the content organiser from an SPD workflow ?

Comment: If i use /_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx?op=SubmitFile, then that i hope should push the document out of the drop off library, but how can i craft a SOAP (PUT ??) in Sharepoint designer workflow ?

Comment: there is a workflow action called Submit File using... then you can enter your asmx url onto that and it will submit.. but i cannot find this on SPD online... Why is this so difficult... Can anyone help me ?